# React not updating style

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to change style when a button is clicked using React. I can see value is changing when button is clicked, but style is not changing. I've been writing in many ways with no luck.

```
export const Paragraph = () => {
    var state = 'none'
    const changeState = () => {
        state = state == 'none' ? 'inline-block' : 'none'
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p style={{display: state}}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: where is the button and its `handleClick` event handler ?

Comment: also `<p style="display : {{state}}"></p>` though I don't prefer inline styles :)

Comment: @niceman JSX allows for passing in a style object.

Answer (score 1):

Better way to set a class instead inline styles.

```
 class Paragraph extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            isClicked: false
        };
    }
    onClick(){
        let condition = this.state.isClicked;
        this.setState({isClicked: !condition})
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>
                <p className={this.state.isClicked? "class_1" : "class_2"}></p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```